# class property becomes undefined after adding an eventlistener inside the constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, html5-canvas, addeventlistener

I am trying to create a class for drawing using typescript, but the property `canvas` becomes undefined if I add an event listener inside the constructor.
here is my code:

```
export class Canvas {
    private canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
    constructor() {
        this.canvas = document.getElementById("main_canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
        this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", this.method1)
    }
    method1() {
        let context = this.canvas.getContext("2d") as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
        context.moveTo(0, 0);
    }
}
```

here is the error:

```
Canvas.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getContext')
    at HTMLCanvasElement.method1
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to bind the callback. Either do:

```js
this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", this.method1.bind(this))
```

or

```js
this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", () => this.method1())
```

In your inital code, you set the callback to a function pointer (`this.method1`), which will be executed with `this` refering to its current value in the executing context. In a click handler, that should be the clicked element, so `this` is not your object, but the HTML canvas element. And since the canvas has no property `canvas`, you get the error.

By binding the function with `bind()`, you get a new function, where `this` refers to whatever you put into bind.

In an arrow function, `this` always refers to what `this` is where the arrow function is declared.